# Issues with undefined function that is in fact defined

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I didn't build this PHP file, but I am trying to figure out why it is giving me errors. If the "Block layout mode" ACF variable is set to "Modal" then the block works, but gives me this error. "Undefined variable $vids on line 176". If I select the "Embed & Thumbnail" mode, then none of the block is displayed and I get this error. "Call to undefined function vc_embed_layout() on line 252". I can't pin down why this is happening, and I haven't been able to find any unclosed tags or anything in my php file. This is the file in question, and I've marked the lines that trigger errors.

```
<?php
global $theme_text_domain;

$block_class_identifier = 'blk__vidcol';

// default variables
$block_id = $top_class = $top_style = $inner_class = $inner_style = '';

// check for custom id
$block_id .= BLOCK::set_id( get_sub_field('content_block_id') );

// set block class, $i comes from FLEX class loop and represents the block order on a page
$top_class .= BLOCK::set_standard_classes( $i );
$top_class .= BLOCK::set_custom_classes( get_sub_field('content_block_classes') );

// check for top padding adjustment
$top_class .= BLOCK::set_padding_class( get_sub_field('block_padding_adjustment') );
$top_style .= BLOCK::set_padding_style( get_sub_field('block_padding_adjustment'), get_sub_field('custom_top_padding'), get_sub_field('custom_bottom_padding'));

// check for custom color theme
$top_style .= BLOCK::set_colors( get_sub_field('color_theme'), get_sub_field('text_color'), get_sub_field('custom_background_color') );

// check for width settings
$inner_class .= BLOCK::set_width_class( get_sub_field('content_width') );
$inner_style .= BLOCK::set_width_style( get_sub_field('content_width'), get_sub_field('custom_maximum_content_width') );

$block_assets = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/blocks/' . basename(__FILE__, '.php') . '/assets/';


/*
CUSTOM BLOCK SPECIFIC SETUP
 */

$layout = get_sub_field('block_layout_mode');
$top_class .= ' layout-' . $layout;


// title color
$h2_style = (get_sub_field('color_theme') == 'custom') ? ' color: ' . get_sub_field('custom_title_color') . ';' : '';





/**
 * outputs code for the modal version of the video collection block
 * @return html output
 */
if (!function_exists('vc_modal_layout')) {
function vc_modal_layout() {
    global $block_class_identifier;
    $cta_label = get_sub_field('cta_label');
    $counter = 0;


    $cta = array(
        'style' => get_sub_field('cta_style'),
        'button_color' => get_sub_field('button_color'),
        'button_text_color' => get_sub_field('button_color')
    );
    $cta_class = BLOCK::get_cta_style( $cta, '.' . $block_class_identifier . ' .button');
?>

    <?php // list section ?>
    <?php if( have_rows('videos') ): ?>
    <div class="vid-container">
        <?php while ( have_rows('videos') ) : the_row(); ?>

            <?php if ($counter == 0): ?>

            <div class="vid-featured">
                <div class="video-wrapper">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_sub_field('youtube_embed_code'); ?>?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <a class="vid_overlay" data-fancybox data-src="#<?php echo $block_class_identifier; ?>_vid_0" href="javascript:;"></a>
                </div>

                <!-- modal -->
                <div id="<?php echo $block_class_identifier; ?>_vid_0" class="modal video-modal" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="modal-inner">
                        <h3><?php echo get_sub_field('video_title'); ?></h3>
                        <div class="video-wrapper">
                            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_sub_field('youtube_embed_code'); ?>?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="vid-list">

            <?php else: ?>

                    <div class="vid-item">
                        <div class="item-btn">
                            <a class="button <?php echo $cta_class; ?>" data-fancybox data-src="#<?php echo $block_class_identifier; ?>_vid_<?php echo $counter; ?>" href="javascript:;"><?php echo $cta_label; ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-title"><?php echo get_sub_field('video_title'); ?></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- modal -->
                    <div id="<?php echo $block_class_identifier; ?>_vid_<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="modal video-modal" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="modal-inner">
                            <h3><?php echo get_sub_field('video_title'); ?></h3>
                            <div class="video-wrapper">
                                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_sub_field('youtube_embed_code'); ?>?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php $counter++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        No videos defined.
    <?php endif; ?>
<?
}
}





/**
 * outputs code for the embed version of the video collection block
 * @return html output
 */
if (!function_exists('vc_embed_layout')) {
function vc_embed_layout($vids, $i) {
?>
    <?php if ( $vids ): ?> **this is line 176**

    <div class="vid-container2">

        <h2 class="vid-title"><?php echo $vids[0]['video_title']; ?></h2>

        <div class="vid-container2-inner">

            <div class="vid-embed">
                <div class="video-wrapper">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $vids[0]['youtube_embed_code']; ?>?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="vid-thumbnails">
                <?php foreach ($vids as $key => $vid): ?>
                    <?php $wrap_class = ($key == 0) ? ' tn-hide' : ''; ?>

                    <div class="tn-wrapper <?php echo $wrap_class; ?>" data-embed="<?php echo $vid['youtube_embed_code']; ?>" data-title="<?php echo $vid['video_title']; ?>">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $vid['youtube_embed_code']; ?>/mqdefault.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var vid_swap = function() {
                $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .vid-embed').css({opacity: 1});

                $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .tn-wrapper').on('click', function(e) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var embed_id = $this.attr('data-embed');
                    var title = $this.attr('data-title');
                    console.log('embed = ' + embed_id);

                    $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .vid-title').animate({opacity: 0}, 100);
                    $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .vid-embed').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
                        $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .vid-embed, .block_<?php echo $i; ?> .vid-title').css('visiblity','hidden');
                        $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .vid-title').html( title ); 
                        $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .vid-embed iframe').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + embed_id);
                        $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .tn-wrapper.tn-hide').removeClass('tn-hide');
                        $this.addClass('tn-hide');
                        $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .vid-title').css('visiblity','visible').delay(500).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
                        $('.block_<?php echo $i; ?> .vid-embed').delay(500).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
                    });
                });
            }

            jQuery(document).on('block_init', vid_swap);
        </script>
    </div>

    <?php else: ?>
        No videos defined.
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
}
}

?>



<section id="<?php echo $block_id; ?>" class="<?php echo $block_class_identifier; ?> <?php echo $top_class; ?>" style="<?php echo $top_style; ?>">
    <div class="inner <?php echo $inner_class; ?>" style="<?php echo $inner_style; ?>">

        <?php // title section ?>
        <?php if (get_sub_field('title')): ?>
        <h2 style="<?php echo $h2_style; ?>"><?php echo get_sub_field('title'); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $vids = get_sub_field('videos'); ?>
        <?php if ($layout == 'modal') vc_modal_layout($vids); ?>
        <?php if ($layout == 'embed') vc_embed_layout($vids, $i); ?> **This is line 252**


    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: have you stepped through it with xdebug or something similar?

Comment: Nope, I've never used a debugger before, but I can give it a try!

Comment: Oooo after it's setup and working you're going to love it! look into setting up xdebug with your IDE/text-editor and you'll soon get to the root of your problem :)

Comment: Yeah I use Atom, and looks like there's an extension that hooks up with it!

Answer (score 1):

You're not accepting any arguments in `vc_modal_layout()` function declaration.

```
if (!function_exists('vc_embed_layout')) {
  function vc_embed_layout() {
```

needs to have parameters in order to accept arguments.

something like this is what you're looking for:

```
if (!function_exists('vc_embed_layout')) {
  function vc_embed_layout($vids=[], $i=0) {
```

And it's the same idea with `vc_modal_layout`, the function needs to be able to accept the variables from outside it.

When we call a function, the function needs to be able to accept all arguments passed to it. And all variables we use need to be defined, if there's a risk of them being undefined or empty arrays, we can check them with `if(!empty($var))` or `if(isset($var))`

An alternative to passing the variable to the function is to access it as a global. But it's generally better to pass the variable to the function because when we pass the variable to a function in PHP it works with a copy of the variable's value inside the function. When we do something like this:

```
$var = 10;
function doIt(){
  global $var;
  $var++;
}
doit();
echo $var;
```

we could overcomplicate things..

let's have a closer look here:

```
if ($layout == 'modal') vc_modal_layout($vids);

if ($layout == 'embed') vc_embed_layout($vids, $i); ?> **This is line 252**


function vc_modal_layout(){ ... }
// should be:
function vc_modal_layout($vids){ ... }

function vc_embed_layout($vids, $i) 
// looks good.
```

Aside from that, nothing stands out as really unusual & I'd want to have a look at the actual site to tinker with this problem further.

Comment: This is just a block that's being pulled into the middle of a template, so the loop does actually wrap around it.

Comment: update my answer. did that help? if you're pulling in a partial you might need to pass the current-scope to that partial. `global $post wp_query_set($partial_post, $post)`

Comment: edited my answer one last time. there are a lot of thing out of sorts in the code presented, but I think this is the root of your problem. Use what I've mentioned above along with `if(!empty($vids)):` on line 176 and it should work.

Comment: That did fix the error related to line 176. I still have the error on line 252 when I select the Embed and Thumbnail version, however.

Comment: updated my answer, the code in your question is still missing a parameter in `vc_modal_layout()`, which should be `vc_modal_layout($vids)`